# Call REST service while impersonating a user that is already authorized to the glasfish server

Tags: rest, authentication, glassfish, client, impersonation

- There are two web-applications deployed on a glassfish server.
- Both web applications provide a REST web service.
- the access to both web-services is secured via glassfish security constraints (at the moment BASIC Auth and file-realm).

Let's say a user is accessing the service of web application A. After he is authorized, service A wants to call service B via REST client.

Is there a way for a service to impersonate a user that is already authorized to the glasfish server? Maybe something like forwarding the security context or editing the headers? Is there another Filter?

```
@Context
private SecurityContext securityContext;

username = securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
password = ???    

client.addFilter(new com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on the authentication scheme, but in some cases you could consider extracting the Authorization header received by Service A and pass it to Service B. That would work with basic authentication.

You should be able to use @HeaderParam to do that, like in the following snippet:

```
@GET
@Path("/resourceA")
public void doSomething(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorization) {
  // now I can call resourceB and use 'authorization'
}
```

Comment: Basic works for me! Could you tell me how? Maybe with a code example? I couldn't find something like that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me! (I don't have enough Reputation to "vote-up" yet. Sorry